# npm not installing any packages regardless there is plenty of space available

Tags: node.js, centos, npm

I am trying to install npm packages on a machine, Disk Space is 1.8TB and only 3% is used so far but whenever I run any npm install command it gives ENOSPC error. Whether I run it local user or with -g. Following is my error stack:

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/moment/2.10.3/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/moment/2.10.3/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/babel-core/5.7.4/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/babel-core/5.7.4/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "pm2"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ENOSPC
npm ERR! errno -28

npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC, write
npm ERR! nospc This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! nospc and is related to insufficient space on your system.
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/babel-core/5.7.4/package.tgz

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

I have emptied the tmp folder and checked it, there were less errors but the ENOSPC remains there.

This is my disk stats, my operating environment is centos:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G   20G     0 100% /
devtmpfs         64G  212K   64G   1% /dev
tmpfs            64G     0   64G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md2         20G   20G     0 100% /
devtmpfs         64G  212K   64G   1% /dev
/dev/md3        1.8T   46G  1.7T   3% /data
/dev/md2         20G   20G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named
/dev/md2         20G   20G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/var/named
/dev/md2         20G   20G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
/dev/md2         20G   20G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.rfc1912.zones
/dev/md2         20G   20G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key
/dev/md2         20G   20G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind
/dev/md2         20G   20G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.iscdlv.key
/dev/md2         20G   20G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.root.key
/dev/md2         20G   20G     0 100% /home/<some user>/<some dir>
```

It will be a great help. I have checked some other forums and tried their solutions such as emptying the tmp folder and this all. But now the errors are different and it doesn't seem like an error with the tmp.

Thank you.

Comment: Your root partition is full. See the first line of your output. `/root` is not under `/data` which is where all your available space is.

Comment: thank you. i am just a novice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your partition is full. The log clearly shows root at 100%

Answer (score 0):

As your log says, the problem is when npm is trying to unsuccessfully untar this file /root/.npm/moment/2.10.3/package.tgz

Try removing it manually and then run npm install again.

Another quite strange thing is that you are trying to install the packages in /root dir, I think that this is not ok at all. Anyway, in that case, are you running npm install as root?, if not this is clearly a permisssions problem.

Regards,
Colo